# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate following integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sin x}$$

My try:

Let $\ln\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)=u \implies \sin x=\frac{a(e^u-1)}{b(e^u+1)}$
$$\cos x dx=\frac{2a e^u du}{b(e^u+1)^2}$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sin x}$$$$=\int_0^{\ln\left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)}\frac{2bu e^u du}{(e^u-1)\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)e^{2u}+2(b^2+a^2)e^u+b^2-a^2}}$$
The substitution becomes very complicated. I got stuck here. Someone please help me solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use Feynman's trick
$$I(b)=\int \log\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)\, \frac{dx}{\sin x}$$
$$I'(b)=\int \frac{2 a}{a^2-b^2 \sin ^2(x)} dx$$

Comment: Can you tell me next step? please

Comment: @Jyerkimenon. Compute the definite integral corresponding to $I'(b)$. Then integrate wrt  $b$ and remember that $I(0)= ??$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\frac{a+b\sin x}{a-b\sin x}\right)\cdot \frac{dx}{\sin x}=\int_0^{\pi/2} dx\int_{-b}^b\frac{dt}{a+t\sin x}$$
But we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2} dx\int_{-b}^b\frac{dt}{a+t\sin x}=\int_{-b}^b dt\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a+t\sin x}=\int_{-b}^b\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}\left(\arctan\frac {a+t}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}-\arctan\frac t{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}\right)dt\\
=\int_{-b}^b\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}\arctan\frac {a+t}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}dt\\
=\left[\arctan^2\frac{a+t}{\sqrt{a^2-t^2}}\right]_{t=-b}^b$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $|z|<1$ we have

$$\log\left(\frac{1+z\sin t}{1-z\sin t}\right) = 2\operatorname{arctanh}(z\sin t)=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\left(\sin t\right)^{2n+1} $$
and since $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin t\right)^{2n}\,dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$ we may check that

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\left(\frac{1+z\sin t}{1-z\sin t}\right)\frac{dt}{\sin t}=\pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{4^n(2n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}=\pi\arcsin(z). $$
This sets the case $|b|<|a|$ and I leave to you to cover the other one, by replacing $z$ in the above lines with $\frac{1}{w}$.